# Probabilistic data structure for checking if item within range of intervals

Tags: data-structures, hash, probability, intervals, bloom-filter

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Given a set of intervals [[s1,e1],[s2,e2],[s3,e3],[s4,34],...] where each interval consists of start and end and all the intervals are disjoint, tell if the point X belongs to one of the intervals or not in constant time where false positives are allowed but no false negatives and uses constant amount of memory independent of the input [such hashing etc..]

So mainly bloom filter can be used for point queries, but it's not efficient to store each point in the intervals in the bloom filter, and using Tries would yield a logarithmic runtime, also the memory usage should be constant and not related to the intervals count [hyper parameter]

I tried to look around for existing DSor by tweaking existing DS but was not able to find similar DS, so any suggestions how this can be solved if any ?

Comment: How much preprocessing time are you allowed to use? And just to confirm, you're given all the intervals up front?

Comment: Hey,
Initially the intervals are given, but they can update through add/delete so the update time should be minimalist, so to build the initial state up to o(n^2) is allowed but for update(insert, delete) it should be near log(n) where n is the number of the intervals, as of course if there are better bounds then would be great

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a slightly modified ["Golomb-compressed sequence" (GCS)](https://www.cs.amherst.edu/~ccmcgeoch/cs34/papers/cacheefficientbloomfilters-jea.pdf) (see "Cache-, Hash- and Space-Efficient Bloom Filters" / F Putze, P Sanders, J Singler). Instead of single entries, you can store start / stop pairs.

You need to split the GCS in blocks. Each block contains a certain range. Because a start / stop pair might not be within the same block, for each block you need to store one additional bit so you know the first entry is a start or stop block. Each block would need to be maintained and updated separately. Having smaller blocks means faster updates, but also more space is needed, because there is an overhead per block. Maybe you want to maintain each block as a separate array, and then you need an array of pointers to all blocks.

A sample implementation of a static GCS is [here](https://github.com/FastFilter/fastfilter_java/tree/master/fastfilter/src/test/java/org/fastfilter/gcs). It doesn't contain start / stop pairs however.